# Integrating SQLServer and H2 in Spring Boot Application

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to integrate SQL Server 2016 and H2 in-memory database for one of my Spring Boot project. All the configuration is set and I'm able to load persistence-unit for both database without any problem. Also, I can query for SQL Server Database and I'm getting my data too. Sql Server JPA configuration is my primary configuration. But, somehow JPA is not able to create entity in H2 database. And after seeing log, I came into the conclusion that the entity that I'm trying to create in H2 is actually trying to find that in SqlServer Datbase. Some part of log for this complain is below:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'person'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:232)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1672)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:460)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:405)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7535)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2438)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:208)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:183)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:348)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy152.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

More detail log is posted below. Below are the classes that I've done and configured till now.

application.properties

```
#Profile Properties
spring.profiles.active=local

# DataSource Properties for SQL Server
app.sqlserver.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://XYZ;database=PQR
app.sqlserver.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
app.sqlserver.jpa.properties.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
app.sqlserver.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
app.sqlserver.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=<custom_dialect_class>
app.sqlserver.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
app.sqlserver.jpa.show-sql=true

# DataSource Properties for H2
app.h2.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:~/h2/TMV
app.h2.datasource.platform=h2
app.h2.datasource.username=sa
app.h2.datasource.password=
app.h2.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
app.h2.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create #here I tried using ddl-auto=create
app.h2.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
app.h2.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
app.h2.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
app.h2.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2_console
```

SQLServerDataSourceConfig.java

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.PersistenceUnitManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.AbstractJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "sqlServerEntityManager",
        basePackages = "com.xyz.persistence.dao",
        transactionManagerRef = "sqlServerTransactionManager"
)
public class SQLServerDataSourceConfig {

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private PersistenceUnitManager persistenceUnitManager;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.sqlserver.jpa")
    public JpaProperties sqlServerJpaProperties(){
        return new JpaProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.sqlserver.datasource")
    public DataSource sqlServerDataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean sqlServerEntityManager(
            JpaProperties sqlServerJpaProperties) {
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder = createEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(sqlServerJpaProperties);
        return builder
                .dataSource(sqlServerDataSource())
                .packages("com.xyz.persistence.domain")
                .persistenceUnit("SQLServer-PU")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JpaTransactionManager sqlServerTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory sqlServerEntityManager) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(sqlServerEntityManager);
    }

    private EntityManagerFactoryBuilder createEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(JpaProperties sqlServerJpaProperties) {
        JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = createJpaVendorAdapter(sqlServerJpaProperties);
        return new EntityManagerFactoryBuilder(jpaVendorAdapter,
                sqlServerJpaProperties.getProperties(), this.persistenceUnitManager);
    }

    private JpaVendorAdapter createJpaVendorAdapter(JpaProperties jpaProperties) {
        AbstractJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setShowSql(jpaProperties.isShowSql());
        adapter.setDatabase(jpaProperties.getDatabase());
        adapter.setDatabasePlatform(jpaProperties.getDatabasePlatform());
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(jpaProperties.isGenerateDdl());
        return adapter;
    }
}
```

H2DataSourceConfig.java

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.PersistenceUnitManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.AbstractJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "h2EntityManager",
        basePackages = "com.xyz.persistence.daoh2",
        transactionManagerRef = "h2TransactionManager"
)
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.xyz.persistence.domainh2"})
public class H2DataSourceConfig {

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private PersistenceUnitManager persistenceUnitManager;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.h2.jpa")
    public JpaProperties sqlServerJpaProperties() {
        return new JpaProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.h2.datasource")
    public DataSource sqlServerDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean h2EntityManager(
            JpaProperties h2JpaProperties) {
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder = createEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(h2JpaProperties);
        return builder
                .dataSource(sqlServerDataSource())
                .packages("com.xyz.persistence.domainh2")
                .persistenceUnit("H2-PU")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager h2TransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory h2EntityManager) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(h2EntityManager);
    }

    private EntityManagerFactoryBuilder createEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(JpaProperties h2JpaProperties) {
        JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = createJpaVendorAdapter(h2JpaProperties);
        return new EntityManagerFactoryBuilder(jpaVendorAdapter,
                h2JpaProperties.getProperties(), this.persistenceUnitManager);
    }

    private JpaVendorAdapter createJpaVendorAdapter(JpaProperties jpaProperties) {
        AbstractJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setShowSql(jpaProperties.isShowSql());
        adapter.setDatabase(jpaProperties.getDatabase());
        adapter.setDatabasePlatform(jpaProperties.getDatabasePlatform());
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(jpaProperties.isGenerateDdl());
        return adapter;
    }
}
```

`PersonDao.java` is the class that is inside “`com.xyz.persistence.daoh2`”

```
import com.xyz.persistence.domainh2.Person;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface PersonDao extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
}
```

`CustomerDao.java` is the class that is inside “`com.xyz.persistence.dao`”

```
import com.xyz.persistence.domain.Customer;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CustomerDao extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

}
```

Person.class

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =  GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME",nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
}
```

Customer.class

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =  GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME",nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
}
```

This is my `H2DataLoader.java` class which `implements CommandLineRunner` to run this class at the time of deployment.

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class H2DataLoader implements CommandLineRunner {

    @PersistenceContext(name = "h2EntityManager")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        try {
            Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
            query.setParameter(1, 1L);
            query.setParameter(2, "Hello");
            query.setParameter(3, "World");
            query.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error Occurred: {}", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Spring Boot's main ApiApplication.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@SpringBootApplication(
        scanBasePackages = { "com.xyz.persistence" },
        exclude = HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class
)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAsync
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class ApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Finally this is my `build.gradle` contents:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.6.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')

    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    compile('com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc')

    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')

    runtime('com.h2database:h2')
}
```

While running this application it gives following information/errors in console:

```
.....
    [INFO ] 2018-01-18 11:38:41.984 [restartedMain] o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'H2-PU'
    [INFO ] 2018-01-18 11:38:44.950 [restartedMain] o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'H2-PU'
    [INFO ] 2018-01-18 11:38:45.043 [restartedMain] o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'SQLServer-PU'
    [INFO ] 2018-01-18 11:38:46.059 [restartedMain] o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'SQLServer-PU'
    [INFO ] 2018-01-18 11:38:48.122 [restartedMain] o.s.a.f.CglibAopProxy - Final method [public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest)] cannot get proxied via CGLIB: Calls to this method will NOT be routed to the target instance and might lead to NPEs against uninitialized fields in the proxy instance.
    ……
    Hiding endpoints mapping details, because this is my official project.
    ……
    o.s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8084 (http)
    Hibernate: 
        INSERT 
        INTO
            person
            (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) 
        VALUES
            (?, ?, ?)
    [WARN ] 2018-01-18 11:38:54.600 [restartedMain] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 208, SQLState: S0002
    [ERROR] 2018-01-18 11:38:54.600 [restartedMain] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - Invalid object name 'person'.
    [ERROR] 2018-01-18 11:38:54.615 [restartedMain] c.h.m.p.c.H2DataLoader - Error Occurred: {}
    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1700)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:70)
        at com.hms.matching.persistence.config.H2DataLoader.run(H2DataLoader.java:34)
        at com.hms.matching.persistence.config.H2DataLoader$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$28072180.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
        at com.hms.matching.persistence.config.H2DataLoader$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d87b2678.run(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:732)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:716)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
        at com…...api.ApiApplication.main(ApiApplication.java:24)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:194)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1373)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.executeUpdate(SQLQueryImpl.java:373)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.internalExecuteUpdate(QueryImpl.java:405)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:61)
        ... 27 common frames omitted
    Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'person'.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:232)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1672)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:460)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:405)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7535)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2438)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:208)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:183)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:348)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy152.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
        ... 32 common frames omitted
    [INFO ] 2018-01-18 11:38:54.631 [restartedMain] o.s.b.a.l.AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer - 

    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    [ERROR] 2018-01-18 11:38:54.662 [restartedMain] o.s.b.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:735)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:716)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
        at com……….api.ApiApplication.main(ApiApplication.java:24)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
    Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:526)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
        at com.hms.matching.persistence.config.H2DataLoader$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d87b2678.run(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:732)
        ... 11 common frames omitted
    Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:58)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
        ... 22 common frames omitted
    [INFO ] 2018-01-18 11:38:54.662 [restartedMain] o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7ab1fbb9: startup date [Thu Jan 18 11:38:31 CST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
```

I don’t know why it is trying to look for Person object in SQL Server. Do anyone have some idea on this. I'm looking after this issue for last 24 hrs. But, didn't find anything. Person table should be created in H2 database. Everything is fine SQL Server side.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve your problem but :

This is not the way JPA is supposed to work. Instead create a `new Person()` object, which should be an `@Entity`, and set its attributes, then `entityManager.persist(person)`.